# Table setup and MMult funtion in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following problem using MMult function in Excel.

Unfortunately, I cannot post pictures here because I am new to the forum, sorry for that. So here is the link for the picture I refer to: https://postimg.org/image/k4zh64puz/

[image]

I have a big table set up in the format the B1:E2 table in the picture has. When I use the transpose formula in A4, it give me the value in B4, which is **wrong**.

When I set up the table in a vertical format as in table B6:C9, the function in A11 gives the right solution to the MMult calculation, like in B11.

Any idea on how I can achieve the **green result with the B1:E2 table**?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Excel's [MMULT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MMULT-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=UShttps://support.office.com/en-us/article/MMULT-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

> "The number of columns in Array1 must be the same as the number of
>   rows in Array2."

So in your second example the first array must be transposed since it contains rows instead of columns. The second array must not be transposed since it contains rows already.

```
{=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(C6:C9),B6:B9)}
```

In your first example the second array must be transposed since the first array contains columns already but the second array contains also columns while it should contain rows.

So in your first example:

```
{=MMULT(B1:E1,TRANSPOSE(B2:E2))}
```

Since your Excel seems to have semicolon as formula parameter separator:

```
{=MMULT(B1:E1;TRANSPOSE(B2:E2))}
```

The formulas must be entered as array formulas. So make sure to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing the formula.

In this concrete example the MMULT would work as an ordinary formula if no transposing would be necessary since the result is a 1 x 1 matrix only. But [TRANSPOSE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) needs to be in array context in any cases.

Comment: @axelRichter Why the array formula markings? { } I did not think MMULT needed them.

Comment: @Forward Ed: Have you tried it as a ordinary formula? Has it worked? Btw.: [MMULT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MMULT-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US): "Note: To work correctly, the formula in the example needs to be entered as an array formula in the Excel program." and [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US): "The key to getting TRANSPOSE to work: Make sure to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing the formula."

Comment: yeah I have tried it as an ordinary formula.  Its probably the transpose part that I never had to do... I know what it was.  I only needed a one cell answer so after MMULTI I was only ever dealing with a 1X1 matrix.  if you need the whole matrix displayed ie more than one cell then you need to either do the array, or index and pull the individual values.  So yes, I will concur that most of the time you really do want { } (CSE) for MMULTI